# How does SPIN decide the order of process execution in atomic processes?

Tags: model-checking, spin, promela

I am trying to figure out how SPIN chooses the order in which to execute and terminate processes in the following example. I realize that a main focus of SPIN is analyzing concurrent processes, but for my purposes I am just interested in simple linear execution. In the following example I just want step1() then step2() to be executed in that order.

```
int globA;
int globB;

proctype step1() {
  atomic {
    globA = 1;
  }
}

proctype step2() { 
  atomic {
    globB = 2;
  }
}

init { 
  atomic {
    run step1();
    run step2();
  }
}
```

However, even with the atomic {} declarations, the processes become interleaved in their execution. Using the command `spin -p my_pml_code.pml` I get the following 3 outputs only (I ran it many times and these were the only outputs).

Run 1:

```
  0:    proc  - (:root:) creates proc  0 (:init:)
Starting step1 with pid 1
  1:    proc  0 (:init::1) creates proc  1 (step1)
  1:    proc  0 (:init::1) pml_testing/transition_testing.pml:16 (state 1)  [(run step1())]
Starting step2 with pid 2
  2:    proc  0 (:init::1) creates proc  2 (step2)
  2:    proc  0 (:init::1) pml_testing/transition_testing.pml:17 (state 2)  [(run step2())]
  3:    proc  2 (step2:1) pml_testing/transition_testing.pml:11 (state 1)   [globB = 2]
  4:    proc  1 (step1:1) pml_testing/transition_testing.pml:6 (state 1)    [globA = 1]
  4:    proc  2 (step2:1)               terminates
  4:    proc  1 (step1:1)           terminates
  4:    proc  0 (:init::1)       terminates
3 processes created
```

The order is proc 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 ->2 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0

Run 2:

```
  0:    proc  - (:root:) creates proc  0 (:init:)
Starting step1 with pid 1
  1:    proc  0 (:init::1) creates proc  1 (step1)
  1:    proc  0 (:init::1) pml_testing/transition_testing.pml:16 (state 1)  [(run step1())]
Starting step2 with pid 2
  2:    proc  0 (:init::1) creates proc  2 (step2)
  2:    proc  0 (:init::1) pml_testing/transition_testing.pml:17 (state 2)  [(run step2())]
  3:    proc  1 (step1:1) pml_testing/transition_testing.pml:6 (state 1)    [globA = 1]
  4:    proc  2 (step2:1) pml_testing/transition_testing.pml:11 (state 1)   [globB = 2]
  4:    proc  2 (step2:1)               terminates
  4:    proc  1 (step1:1)           terminates
  4:    proc  0 (:init::1)       terminates
3 processes created
```

The order is proc 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0

Run 3:

```
  0:    proc  - (:root:) creates proc  0 (:init:)
Starting step1 with pid 1
  1:    proc  0 (:init::1) creates proc  1 (step1)
  1:    proc  0 (:init::1) pml_testing/transition_testing.pml:16 (state 1)  [(run step1())]
Starting step2 with pid 2
  2:    proc  0 (:init::1) creates proc  2 (step2)
  2:    proc  0 (:init::1) pml_testing/transition_testing.pml:17 (state 2)  [(run step2())]
  3:    proc  2 (step2:1) pml_testing/transition_testing.pml:11 (state 1)   [globB = 2]
  3:    proc  2 (step2:1)               terminates
  4:    proc  1 (step1:1) pml_testing/transition_testing.pml:6 (state 1)    [globA = 1]
  4:    proc  1 (step1:1)           terminates
  4:    proc  0 (:init::1)       terminates
3 processes created
```

The order is proc 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 ->2 -> 2 -> 1 -> 1 -> 0

The output I am trying to get it simply: proc 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 ->1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 2 -> 0

I realize that proc 0 can't terminate until 1 and 2 have terminated, but why are the terminations of 2 and 1 being interleaved non-deterministicly? Any why is SPIN randomly choosing between executing proc 1 and proc 2 when the init function is atomic and therefore should be executed in order? And why can I get proc 2 to start and terminate before proc 1 (in Run 3) but not the other way around?

Note: I have also tested this using `dstep` instead of `atomic` and I get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me try give **short** answers to each of your questions:

> **1.** I realise that proc 0 can't terminate until 1 and 2 have terminated, but why are the terminations of 2 and 1 being interleaved non-deterministically?

The processes always terminate in a *deterministic* fashion: `2` terminates before `1`, `1` before `0` and `0` is always the last one. However, there is nothing special about process termination: it is simply the *final transition* that is taken by a process. As a result, process interleaving is possible at any point in time in which there are more than one process with an *(immediately)* executable instruction.

> **2.** Any why is SPIN randomly choosing between executing proc 1 and proc 2 when the init function is atomic and therefore should be executed in order?

Although it is true that `init` executes both of his instructions atomically, the important fact to keep in mind is that `step1` and `step2` are independent processes and are executed after `init` exits its **atomic** block: `run` is not a function call, it just **spawns** a process inside the environment with absolutely no guarantee that such process is executed immediately. That might or might not happen depending on whether the *spawned process* has any executable instruction, whether the process that is currently executing is in an atomic sequence and on the outcome of the non-deterministic scheduler process selection.

> **3.** And why can I get proc 2 to start and terminate before proc 1 (in Run 3) but not the other way around?

In **Promela**, processes can only die in reverse order of their creation, as indicated in the [docs](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/_pid.html):

```
When a process terminates, it can only die and make its _pid number
available for the creation of another process, if and when it has the
highest _pid number in the system. This means that processes can only
die in the reverse order of their creation (in stack order).
```

Therefore, `2` can terminate before `1` because it has higher `_pid` value, whereas `1` must wait upon `2` to be terminate before it can die.

> **4.** How does SPIN decide the order of process execution in atomic processes?

There is no such thing as an **atomic** process if you have more than one in your system. Even if you enclose the whole body of a process inside the **atomic** keyword, the termination step is still *outside* the **atomic** block. The scheduler never interrupts a process executing an atomic sequence, unless the process blocks in front of an instruction that is not executable. In such a case **atomicity is lost** and any other process can be scheduled for execution, as described in the [docs](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/atomic.html):

> If any statement within the atomic sequence blocks, atomicity is lost,
>   and other processes are then allowed to start executing statements.
>   When the blocked statement becomes executable again, the execution of
>   the atomic sequence can be resumed at any time, but not necessarily
>   immediately. Before the process can resume the atomic execution of the
>   remainder of the sequence, the process must first compete with all
>   other active processes in the system to regain control, that is, it
>   must first be scheduled for execution.

---

In your question you state that your goal is to obtain the following *execution-flow*:

```
proc 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 ->1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 2 -> 0
```

In your code example, this *execution-flow* is **forbidden** because it makes process `1` terminate before process `2` and this is not allowed by the rules (see the answer to your third question).

---

> Note: I have also tested this using dstep instead of atomic and I get the same result.

No statement inside your **atomic** block can block, therefore there is absolutely no difference among using `d_step` or `atomic` in your code. However, I invite you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126629/atomic-sequences-in-promela-contradictory-in-documentation/43138508#43138508) to get an insight of similarities and differences among **atomic** and **d_step**.

---

**EXAMPLE EXECUTION FLOW:**

Second, let me try a **deeper** answer level based on the analysis of the *execution-flow*.

In your code **example** there are three processes.

`init` is *(always)* the **first** process to be created *(when available)*, and for this reason it is *(always)* assigned `_pid` equal to `0` and scheduled for first. Since the whole body of the `init` process is enclosed in an **atomic** block, this process executes `run step1();` and `run step2()` without interleaving with other processes. Process `step1` is assigned `_pid` equal `1`, because it's the second process to be created, whereas process `step2` is assigned `_pid` equal `2`, since it's the third process to be created.

In your example, processes `step1` and `step2` cannot be scheduled for execution until when the `init` process reaches the end of the **atomic**, which in your code example coincides with the end of the `init` code.

When `init` reaches the end of its body, the process  (with `_pid` equal to `0`) cannot die yet because inside the environment there is at least one process with a `_pid` value greater than his own, namely `step1` and `step2`.  Although `init` is blocked, both `step1` and `step2` are ready for execution, so the **non-deterministic scheduler** can arbitrarily select either `step1` or `step2` for execution.

- If `step1` is scheduled first, then it executes its only instruction `globA = 1;` without interleaving with `step2`. Notice that, since there is only one instruction inside the **atomic** block and this instruction is atomic on his own, the **atomic** block is redundant (the same holds for `step2`). Again, since `step1` has `_pid` equal to `1` and there is still a process with higher `_pid` value around, process `step1` cannot die yet. At this point, the only process that can be scheduled for execution is `step2`, which can also terminate because there is no process with higher `_pid` value. This allows `step1` to terminate, which in turn allows `init` to die as well. This *execution-flow* corresponds to your **run 2**.
- If `step2` is scheduled first, then once this process has assigned the value `2` to `globB` and reaches the end of its body, which is **outside** the **atomic** block, there are two possible execution flows:

  - **case A)** the scheduler non-deterministically selects `step2` to execute again, and `step2` terminates; now the only available option for the scheduler is to make `step1` execute its own instruction, make it terminate and then allow `init` to terminate too. This *execution flow* corresponds to **run 1**.
  - **case B)** the scheduler non-deterministically selects `step1` to execute, `step1` assigns `1` to `globA` but cannot terminate because `step2` is still alive; the only process that can be scheduled is `step2`, so the latter terminates after being selected by the scheduler, allowing `step1` and `init` to terminate as well in cascade. This *execution flow* corresponds to **run 3**.

---

**LINEAR EXECUTION:**

The simplest and most obvious way to achieve **linear execution** is to have **only one process** inside your model. It is trivial to see why this is the case. So your example would become:

```cpp
int globA;
int globB;

inline step1()
{
    globA = 1;
}

inline step2()
{
    globB = 2;
}

init
{
    step1();
    step2();
}
```

Having **atomic** blocks in this code is no longer necessary, since there is only one process. Of course, you might frown upon such a trivial solution, so let's see another solution based on a global variable:

```cpp
int globA;
int globB;
bool terminated;

proctype step1()
{
    globA = 1;
    terminated = true;
}

proctype step2()
{
    globB = 2;
    terminated = true;
}

init
{
    run step1();
    terminated -> terminated = false;
    run step2();
    terminated -> terminated = false;
}
```

Differently than your code example, here `globB = 2` can never be executed before `globA = 1` is executed thanks to the *synchronisation* variable `terminated`. However, similarly to your code example, the actual termination of processes `step1` and `step2` is subject to interleaving. **i.e.** if `step1` terminates immediately, so that `step2` is created only after `step1` has completely released the resources it owns, then `step2` is assigned `_pid` equal to `1`; otherwise, `step2` is assigned `_pid` equal to `2`.

The **best solution** I can think of is based on the concept of **message passing**. Basically, the idea is to allow only the process that currently holds a **token** to be scheduled at any given point in time, and to pass around such **token** in the desired scheduling order:

```cpp
int globA;
int globB;

mtype = { TOKEN };

proctype step1(chan in, out)
{
    in ? TOKEN ->
        globA = 1;
        out ! TOKEN;
}

proctype step2(chan in, out)
{
    in ? TOKEN ->
        globB = 2;
        out ! TOKEN;
}

init
{
    chan token_ring[2] = [0] of { mtype };

    run step1(token_ring[0], token_ring[1]);
    run step2(token_ring[1], token_ring[0]);

    token_ring[0] ! TOKEN;

    token_ring[0] ? TOKEN;
}
```

Notice that this solution **forces** only one possible scheduling. This can be verified by running an **interactive simulation**:

```sh
~$ spin -i ring.pml 
Select a statement
    choice 2: proc  0 (:init::1) ring.pml:25 (state 2) [(run step2(token_ring[1],token_ring[0]))]
Select [1-2]: 2
Select a statement
    choice 3: proc  0 (:init::1) ring.pml:27 (state 3) [token_ring[0]!TOKEN]
Select [1-3]: 3
Select a statement
    choice 2: proc  1 (step1:1) ring.pml:9 (state 2) [globA = 1]
Select [1-3]: 2
Select a statement
    choice 2: proc  1 (step1:1) ring.pml:10 (state 3) [out!TOKEN]
Select [1-3]: 2
Select a statement
    choice 1: proc  2 (step2:1) ring.pml:16 (state 2) [globB = 2]
Select [1-3]: 1
Select a statement
    choice 1: proc  2 (step2:1) ring.pml:17 (state 3) [out!TOKEN]
Select [1-3]: 1
Select a statement
    choice 1: proc  2 (step2:1) ring.pml:18 (state 4) <valid end state> [-end-]
Select [1-3]: 1
Select a statement
    choice 1: proc  1 (step1:1) ring.pml:11 (state 4) <valid end state> [-end-]
Select [1-2]: 1
3 processes created
```

As you can see, the *user* is never offered the chance to make any choice, because there is only one possible *execution-flow*. This is obviously due to the fact that **A)** I did not put any instruction before `in!TOKEN` and after `out!TOKEN` **B)** the desired scheduling order coincides with the order in which processes are created.