# Process not terminated causing a "too many processes" error

Tags: spin, promela

It is my first time using spin and I am encountering an error that I do not understand. I am aware that the processes terminates in the same order they are created thus I don't understand why the process of the function I call in a loop does not terminate.
Here is a very simplified version of my code :

```
int limit;

proctype f() {
    limit--;
    printm(limit)
    run g();
}

proctype g() {
    limit++;
}

init {
    limit = 5;
    do
        :: (limit > 0) -> run f();
    od
}
```

The limit variable is created so there is not more than 5 processes `f` running at the same time. The processes `g` does terminate but `f` don't. So I get the error :  `too many processes` 
I would like to know why `f` does not terminate and if there is another way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is based on a false premise: it isn't true that there are never more than 5 processes in your system.

In fact, there can be any number of processes of type `f()`, because there is absolutely no guarantee that the instruction:

```
limit--;
```

is executed right after the process is created with

```
run f();
```

It is possible that the process scheduler lets `init()` execute for several (tens, hundreds, more..) loop iterations before it preempts it and gives a chance to some `f()` to execute anything.

If a process `g()` is created, then this can clearly terminate.

If a process `f()` is created, this can terminate only if there aren't already `255` processes in the system and it is the process `f()` with the highest `pid`, so that it does not have to wait for other processes.

The `init()` process can never terminate.

---

As a possible fix, you might want to try to look into [_nr_pr](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/_nr_pr.html):

```
int limit = 5;

proctype f() {
    printm(limit)
}

init {
    do
        :: (_nr_pr <= (limit + 1)) ->
                run f();
    od
}
```

Comment: It did not solve the issue. This is what made me make the precedent assumption: `Starting g with pid 122
846:    proc 121 (f:1) test.pml:5 (state 2)     [(run g())]
847:    proc 122 (g:1) test.pml:9 (state 1)     [limit = (limit+1)]
                limit = 5
848: proc 122 terminates` As You can see process 122 terminates not 121.

Comment: @guillau4 you were right in pointing out that the previous code example I provided can incur in the same problem as yours. `f()` with `pid` `121` **cannot** terminate before any other process with higher `pid` value is terminated. This does not mean that it will necessarily terminate immediately. The `init()` process can spawn other `f()` processes in the meantime, or another `f()` process can create his own `g()`. I invite you to read [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293090/how-does-spin-decide-the-order-of-process-execution-in-atomic-processes).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, `f()` can not terminate even though it reached the end of its code and I have no way to force this except by forcing all the scheduling?

Comment: @guillau4 Yes, that is possible, if the right circumnstances arise in a given model. I am not aware of any way in which the scheduling can be enforced, so I would try change the model so that no weird situation can arise.