# how to model a queue in promela?

Tags: multithreading, locking, model-checking, promela, spin

Ok, so I'm trying to model a [CLH-RW lock](https://github.com/pramalhe/ConcurrencyFreaks/blob/master/Presentations/CLH-RWLock.pptx) in Promela.

The way the lock works is simple, really:

The queue consists of a `tail`, to which both readers and writers enqueue a node containing a single `bool succ_must_wait` they do so by creating a new node and CAS-ing it with the `tail`.

The tail thereby becomes the node's predecessor, `pred`.

Then they spin-wait on `pred.succ_must_wait` until it is `false`.

Readers first increment a reader counter `ncritR` and then set their own flag to `false`, allowing multiple readers at in the critical section at the same time. Releasing a readlock simply means decrementing `ncritR` again.

Writers wait until `ncritR` reaches zero, then enter the critical section. They do not set their flag to `false` until the lock is released.

I'm kind of struggling to model this in promela, though.

My current attempt (see below) tries to make use of arrays, where each node basically consists of a number of array entries.

This fails because let's say `A` enqueues itself, then `B` enqueues itself. Then the queue will look like this:

```
S <- A <- B
```

Where `S` is a sentinel node.

The problem now is, that when `A` runs to completeness and re-enqueues, the queue will look like

```
S <- A <- B <- A'
```

In actual execution, this is absolutely fine because `A` and `A'` are distinct node objects. And since `A.succ_must_wait` will have been set to `false` when `A` first released the lock, `B` will eventually make progress, and therefore `A'` will eventually make progress.

What happens in the array-based promela model below, though, is that `A` and `A'` occupy the same array positions, causing `B` to miss the fact that `A` has released the lock, thereby creating a deadlock where `B` is (wrongly) waiting for `A'` instead of `A` and `A'` is waiting (correctly) for `B`.

A possible "solution" to this could be to have `A` wait until `B` acknowledges the release. But that would not be true to how the lock works.

Another "solution" would be to wait for a CHANGE in `pred.succ_must_wait`, where a release would increment `succ_must_wait`, rather than reset it to `0`.

But I'm intending to model a version of the lock, where `pred` may change (i.e. where a node may be allowed to disregard some of its predecessors), and I'm not entirely convinced something like the increasing version wouldn't cause an issue with this change.

So what's the "smartest" way to model an implicit queue like this in promela?

```
/* CLH-RW Lock */
/*pid: 0 = init, 1-2 = reader, 3-4 =  writer*/

ltl liveness{ 
    ([]<> reader[1]@progress_reader)
    && ([]<> reader[2]@progress_reader)
    && ([]<> writer[3]@progress_writer)
    && ([]<> writer[4]@progress_writer)
 }

bool initialised = 0;

byte ncritR;
byte ncritW;
byte tail;
bool succ_must_wait[5]
byte pred[5]

init{
    assert(_pid == 0);
    ncritR = 0;
    ncritW = 0;

    /*sentinel node*/
    tail =0;
    pred[0] = 0;
    succ_must_wait[0] = 0;
    initialised = 1;
}

active [2] proctype reader()
{
    assert(_pid >= 1);
    (initialised == 1)
    do
    :: else ->
        succ_must_wait[_pid] = 1;
        atomic {
            pred[_pid] = tail;
            tail = _pid;
        }

        (succ_must_wait[pred[_pid]] == 0)

        ncritR++;
        succ_must_wait[_pid] = 0;
        atomic {
            /*freeing previous node for garbage collection*/
            pred[_pid] = 0;
        }

        /*CRITICAL SECTION*/
progress_reader:
        assert(ncritR >= 1);
        assert(ncritW == 0);

        ncritR--;

        atomic {
            /*necessary to model the fact that the next access creates a new queue node*/
            if
            :: tail == _pid -> tail = 0;
            :: else ->
            fi
        }
    od
}

active [2] proctype writer()
{
    assert(_pid >= 1);
    (initialised == 1)
    do
    :: else -> 
        succ_must_wait[_pid] = 1;

        atomic {
            pred[_pid] = tail;
            tail = _pid;
        }

        (succ_must_wait[pred[_pid]] == 0)
        (ncritR == 0)
        atomic {
            /*freeing previous node for garbage collection*/
            pred[_pid] = 0;
        }
        ncritW++;

        /* CRITICAL SECTION */
progress_writer:
        assert(ncritR == 0);
        assert(ncritW == 1);

        ncritW--;
        succ_must_wait[_pid] = 0;

        atomic {
            /*necessary to model the fact that the next access creates a new queue node*/
            if
            :: tail == _pid -> tail = 0;
            :: else -> 
            fi
        }
    od
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a few notes:

- You don't need to initialize your variables to `0`, since:

  > The default initial value of all variables is zero.

  see the [docs](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/assign.html).
- You don't need to enclose a single instruction inside an [`atomic {}`](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/atomic.html) statement, since any *elementary statement* is executed atomically. For better efficiency of the verification process, whenever possible, you should use [`d_step {}`](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/d_step.html) instead. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126629/atomic-sequences-in-promela-contradictory-in-documentation/43138508#43138508) you can find a related *stackoverflow Q/A* on the topic.
- `init {}` is guaranteed to have `_pid == 0` when one of the two following conditions holds:

  - no `active proctype` is declared
  - `init {}` is declared before any other `active proctype` appearing in the source code

  Active Processes, includig `init {}`, are spawned in order of appearance inside the source code. All other processes are spawned in order of appearance of the corresponding `run ...` statement.

---

I identified the following issues on your model:

- the instruction `pred[_pid] = 0` is useless because that memory location is only read after the assignment `pred[_pid] = tail`
- When you release the successor of a node, you set `succ_must_wait[_pid]` to `0` only and you **don't invalidate** the node instance onto which your successor is waiting for. This is the problem that you identified in your question, but was unable to solve. The solution I propose is to add the following code:

  ```cpp
  pid j;
  for (j: 1..4) {
      if
          :: pred[j] == _pid -> pred[j] = 0;
          :: else -> skip;
      fi
  }
  ```

  This should be enclosed in an `atomic {}` block.
- You correctly set `tail` back to `0` when you find that the node that has just left the critical section is also the `last` node in the queue. You also correctly enclose this operation in an `atomic {}` block. However, it may happen that *--when you are about to enter this `atomic {}` block--* some other process *--who was still waiting in some idle state--* decides to execute the initial atomic block and copies the current value of `tail` *--which corresponds to the node that has just expired--* into his own `pred[_pid]` memory location. If now the node that has just exited the critical section attempts to join it once again, setting his own value of `succ_must_wait[_pid]` to `1`, you will get another instance of *circular wait* among processes. The correct approach is to merge this part with the code releasing the successor.

---

The following inline function can be used to *release the successor* of a given node:

```cpp
inline release_succ(i)
{
    d_step {
        pid j;
        for (j: 1..4) {
            if
                :: pred[j] == i ->
                    pred[j] = 0;
                :: else ->
                    skip;
            fi
        }
        succ_must_wait[i] = 0;
        if
            :: tail == _pid -> tail = 0;
            :: else -> skip;
        fi
    }
}
```

The complete model, follows:

```cpp
byte ncritR;
byte ncritW;
byte tail;
bool succ_must_wait[5];
byte pred[5];

init
{
    skip
}

inline release_succ(i)
{
    d_step {
        pid j;
        for (j: 1..4) {
            if
                :: pred[j] == i ->
                    pred[j] = 0;
                :: else ->
                    skip;
            fi
        }
        succ_must_wait[i] = 0;
        if
            :: tail == _pid -> tail = 0;
            :: else -> skip;
        fi
    }
}

active [2] proctype reader()
{
loop:
    succ_must_wait[_pid] = 1;
    d_step {
        pred[_pid] = tail;
        tail = _pid;
    }

trying:
    (succ_must_wait[pred[_pid]] == 0)

    ncritR++;
    release_succ(_pid);

    // critical section    
progress_reader:
    assert(ncritR > 0);
    assert(ncritW == 0);

    ncritR--;

    goto loop;
}

active [2] proctype writer()
{
loop:
    succ_must_wait[_pid] = 1;

    d_step {
        pred[_pid] = tail;
        tail = _pid;
    }

trying:
    (succ_must_wait[pred[_pid]] == 0) && (ncritR == 0)

    ncritW++;

    // critical section
progress_writer:
    assert(ncritR == 0);
    assert(ncritW == 1);

    ncritW--;

    release_succ(_pid);

    goto loop;
}
```

---

I added the following properties to the model:

- **p0**: the *writer* with `_pid` equal to `4` goes through its progress state infinitely often, provided that it is given the chance to execute some instruction infinitely often:

  ```cpp
  ltl p0 {
     ([]<> (_last == 4)) ->
     ([]<> writer[4]@progress_writer)
  };
  ```

  This property should be `true`.
- **p1**: there is never more than one reader in the critical section:

  ```cpp
  ltl p1 {
      ([] (ncritR <= 1))
  };
  ```

  Obviously, we expect this property to be `false` in a model that matches your specification.
- **p2**: there is never more than one writer in the critical section:

  ```cpp
  ltl p2 {
      ([] (ncritW <= 1))
  };
  ```

  This property should be `true`.
- **p3**: there isn't any node that is the predecessor of two other nodes at the same time, unless such node is node `0`:

  ```cpp
  ltl p3 {
      [] (
          (((pred[1] != 0) && (pred[2] != 0)) -> (pred[1] != pred[2])) &&
          (((pred[1] != 0) && (pred[3] != 0)) -> (pred[1] != pred[3])) &&
          (((pred[1] != 0) && (pred[4] != 0)) -> (pred[1] != pred[4])) &&
          (((pred[2] != 0) && (pred[3] != 0)) -> (pred[2] != pred[3])) &&
          (((pred[2] != 0) && (pred[4] != 0)) -> (pred[2] != pred[4])) &&
          (((pred[3] != 0) && (pred[4] != 0)) -> (pred[3] != pred[4]))
      )
  };
  ```

  This property should be `true`.
- **p4**: it is always true that whenever *writer* with `_pid` equal to `4` tries to access the *critical section* then it will eventually get there:

  ```cpp
  ltl p4 {
      [] (writer[4]@trying -> <> writer[4]@progress_writer)
  };
  ```

  This property should be `true`.

The outcome of the verification matches our expectations:

```sh
~$ spin -search -ltl p0 -a clhrw_lock.pml 
...
Full statespace search for:
    never claim             + (p0)
    assertion violations    + (if within scope of claim)
    acceptance   cycles     + (fairness disabled)
    invalid end states      - (disabled by never claim)

State-vector 68 byte, depth reached 3305, errors: 0
...

~$ spin -search -ltl p1 -a clhrw_lock.pml 
...
Full statespace search for:
    never claim             + (p1)
    assertion violations    + (if within scope of claim)
    acceptance   cycles     + (fairness disabled)
    invalid end states      - (disabled by never claim)

State-vector 68 byte, depth reached 1692, errors: 1
...

~$ spin -search -ltl p2 -a clhrw_lock.pml
...
Full statespace search for:
    never claim             + (p2)
    assertion violations    + (if within scope of claim)
    acceptance   cycles     + (fairness disabled)
    invalid end states      - (disabled by never claim)

State-vector 68 byte, depth reached 3115, errors: 0
...

~$ spin -search -ltl p3 -a clhrw_lock.pml 
...
Full statespace search for:
    never claim             + (p3)
    assertion violations    + (if within scope of claim)
    acceptance   cycles     + (fairness disabled)
    invalid end states      - (disabled by never claim)

State-vector 68 byte, depth reached 3115, errors: 0
...

~$ spin -search -ltl p4 -a clhrw_lock.pml 
...
Full statespace search for:
    never claim             + (p4)
    assertion violations    + (if within scope of claim)
    acceptance   cycles     + (fairness disabled)
    invalid end states      - (disabled by never claim)

State-vector 68 byte, depth reached 3115, errors: 0
...
```