# PROMELA: What are interleavings?

Tags: model, model-checking, promela, spin

Lets say we have this piece of code:

```
int x = 3;
int y = 5;
int z = 0;

active proctype P(){
   if
      :: x > y -> z = x
      :: else -> z = y
   fi
}

active proctype Q(){
    x++
}

active proctype R(){
    y = y - x
}
```

I don't understand what interleavings are. What exactly are interleaving and where and how many are there in my example above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Promela*, a process with an *executable* instruction can be scheduled for execution at any given point in time, provided that no other process is currently executing a [uninterruptible atomic sequence](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/atomic.html).

A single instruction, on its own, it is executed atomically. In order to have multiple instructions in the same atomic sequence, one can use either [`atomic { }`](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/atomic.html) or [`d_step { }`](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/d_step.html). I refer you to [this other question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126629/atomic-sequences-in-promela-contradictory-in-documentation) for learning the difference among the two.

---

In your case, a possible execution trace is:

```
x++           // Q(), x := 4
z = y         // P(), z := 5
y = y - x     // R(), y := 1
```

Another, totally admissible, possible execution trace is:

```
y = y - x     // R(), y := 2
x++           // Q(), x := 4
z = x         // P(), z := 4
```

The processes are *interleaved* with one another, meaning that after each instruction of some process `P_i` (which is not in an uninterruptible atomic sequence), the process `P_i` can be preempted and some other process `P_j` can be scheduled for execution (provided that it actually has to execute something).

It is is nothing different from what happens in a multi-tasking unix machine, in which processes are interleaved one another and compete for access to the CPU.